# Drawer navigation Issues

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, drawer

I faced Drawer navigation error, the Drawer navigation error can occur for various reasons.such as incorrect configuration of navigation libraries or improperly structured navigation code,it is essential to identify the root cause of the issue. The error message itself can give you some clues, but you may need to debug your code

```
> import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { RootSiblingParent } from 'react-native-root-siblings';
import SignIn from '../Screens/SignIn';
import Home from '../Screens/Home';
import ForgotPassword from '../Screens/ForgotPassword';
import ChangePassword from '../Screens/ChangePassword';
import {
    createDrawerNavigator,
    DrawerContentScrollView,
    DrawerItemList,
  } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const CustomDrawer = props => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
          <View
            style={{
             alignSelf:"center",
              padding: 20,
  
            }}
          >
            <View>
              <Text style={{fontSize:18,fontWeight:"bold"}}>BusGo Captain App</Text>
            </View>
           
          </View>
          <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        </DrawerContentScrollView>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 50,
            backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6',
            padding: 20,
          }}
        >

        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
  function DrawerRoutes(){

  
    return(
      
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"
     
        drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
      >
      
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} 
          
          options={{
            headerShown: false ,
            title:'Home',
            drawerIcon:({focused,size})=>(
              <Icon
              name="home"
              size ={size}   
                color='black'
                
              />
              
            )
          }}
        />
        
       
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
  }

function Navigation() {
    return (
        <RootSiblingParent>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
                <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
                <Stack.Screen name="ChangePassword" component={ChangePassword} />
                <Stack.Screen name="DrawerRoutes" component={DrawerRoutes} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </RootSiblingParent>
    );
}

export default Navigation;
```

- TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes
  ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: herme

Comment: What's the question?